# Why does nan appear in loss layer in the first few iterations?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

In the first few iteraions, the loss begin to decrease. But When the iterations reaches a certain amount, loss layer appears nan and the layers hidden ahead is normal.

the data is iamges using hdf5 type and type of loss is euclidean. framwork is caffe.

solver and net is listed as follow.

```
net: "/home/ubuntu/caffe/examples/CaffeTrain/DCSCN_net.prototxt"
test_iter: 250
# Carry out testing every 500 training iterations.
test_interval: 500
# All parameters are from the cited paper above
base_lr: 0.0002
momentum: 0.9
momentum2: 0.999
# rate to a fixed value
lr_policy: "fixed"
# Display every 100 iterations
display: 100
# The maximum number of iterations
max_iter: 60000
# snapshot intermediate results
snapshot: 1500
snapshot_prefix: "/home/ubuntu/caffe/examples/CaffeTrain/DCSCN_net"
# solver mode: CPU or GPU
type: "Adam"
solver_mode: GPU
```

```
name: "DCSRCN"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "/home/ubuntu/caffe/examples/CaffeTrain/train1.txt"
    batch_size: 64
  }
  include: { phase: TRAIN }
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "/home/ubuntu/caffe/examples/CaffeTrain/test1.txt"
    batch_size: 2
  }
  include: { phase: TEST }
}

layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.1
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 32
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    pad: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}


layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "PReLU"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}


layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.1
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 26
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    pad: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}

layer {
  name: "relu2"
  type: "PReLU"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "conv2"
}


layer
{
    name:"drop"
    type:"Dropout"
    bottom:"conv2"
    top:"conv2"
    dropout_param
    {
        dropout_ratio: 0.8
    }
}

layer {
  name: "conv3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "conv3"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.1
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 22
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    pad: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}


layer {
  name: "relu3"
  type: "PReLU"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv3"
}

layer
{
    name:"drop"
    type:"Dropout"
    bottom:"conv3"
    top:"conv3"
    dropout_param
    {
        dropout_ratio: 0.8
    }
}
layer {
  name: "conv4"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv4"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.1
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 18
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    pad: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}

layer {
  name: "relu4"
  type: "PReLU"
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv4"
}

layer
{
    name:"drop"
    type:"Dropout"
    bottom:"conv4"
    top:"conv4"
    dropout_param
    {
        dropout_ratio: 0.8
    }
}
layer {
  name: "conv5"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv5"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.1
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 14
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    pad: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}


layer {
  name: "relu5"
  type: "PReLU"
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "conv5"
}

layer
{
    name:"drop"
    type:"Dropout"
    bottom:"conv5"
    top:"conv5"
    dropout_param
    {
        dropout_ratio: 0.8
    }
}

layer {
  name: "conv6"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "conv6"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.1
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 11 
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    pad: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}

layer {
  name: "relu6"
  type: "PReLU"
  bottom: "conv6"
  top: "conv6"
}

layer
{
    name:"drop"
    type:"Dropout"
    bottom:"conv6"
    top:"conv6"
    dropout_param
    {
        dropout_ratio: 0.8
    }
}

layer {
  name: "conv7"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv6"
  top: "conv7"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.1
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 8
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    pad: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}


layer {
  name: "relu7"
  type: "PReLU"
  bottom: "conv7"
  top: "conv7"
}

layer
{
    name:"drop"
    type:"Dropout"
    bottom:"conv7"
    top:"conv7"
    dropout_param
    {
        dropout_ratio: 0.8
    }
}

layer {
  name: "concatenate1"
  bottom: "conv2"
  bottom: "conv3"
  bottom: "conv4"
  bottom: "conv5"
  bottom: "conv6"
  bottom: "conv7"
  top: "concatenate1"
  type: "Concat"
  concat_param{
   axis: 1
  }
}

layer {
  name: "A1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "concatenate1"
  top: "A1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.1
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 24
    kernel_size: 1
    stride: 1
    pad: 0
    weight_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}

layer {
  name: "reluA1"
  type: "PReLU"
  bottom: "A1"
  top: "A1"
}

layer
{
    name:"drop"
    type:"Dropout"
    bottom:"A1"
    top:"A1"
    dropout_param
    {
        dropout_ratio: 0.8
    }
}

layer {
  name: "B1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "concatenate1"
  top: "B1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.1
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 8
    kernel_size: 1
    stride: 1
    pad: 0
    weight_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}

layer {
  name: "reluB1"
  type: "PReLU"
  bottom: "B1"
  top: "B1"
}

layer
{
    name:"drop"
    type:"Dropout"
    bottom:"B1"
    top:"B1"
    dropout_param
    {
        dropout_ratio: 0.8
    }
} 

layer {
  name: "B2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "B1"
  top: "B2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.1
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 8
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    pad: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}

layer {
  name: "reluB2"
  type: "PReLU"
  bottom: "B2"
  top: "B2"
}
layer
{
    name:"drop"
    type:"Dropout"
    bottom:"B2"
    top:"B2"
    dropout_param
    {
        dropout_ratio: 0.8
    }
}

layer {
  name: "concatenate2"
  bottom: "A1"
  bottom: "B2"
  top: "concatenate2"
  type: "Concat"
  concat_param{
   axis: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv8"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "concatenate2"
  top: "conv8"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.1
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 4
    kernel_size: 1
    stride: 1
    pad: 0
    weight_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}

layer {
  name: "slicer_label"
  type: "Slice"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "label1"
  top: "label2"
  slice_param {
    axis: 1
    slice_point: 4
  }
}

layer{
  name: "diff"
  type: "Eltwise"
  bottom: "label1"
  bottom: "label2"
  top: "diff"
  eltwise_param {
    operation: SUM
    coeff: 1
    coeff: -1
  }
}


layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "EuclideanLoss"
  bottom: "diff"
  bottom: "conv8"
  top: "loss"
}
```

when the loss layer appear nan, the back of iteration will appear the same situation. here is part of log.

```
I0522 10:10:04.978370   950 solver.cpp:239] Iteration 201 (9.82038 iter/s, 0.101829s/1 iters), loss = 0.412089
I0522 10:10:04.978469   950 solver.cpp:258]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.412088 (* 1 = 0.412088 loss)
I0522 10:10:04.978521   950 sgd_solver.cpp:112] Iteration 201, lr = 0.002
I0522 10:10:04.980057   950 sgd_solver.cpp:99] Gradient clipping: scaling down gradients (L2 norm 1.80722 > 1) by scale factor 0.553335
I0522 10:10:04.984403   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer data, top blob data data: 0.44866
I0522 10:10:04.984561   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer data, top blob label data: 0.0258211
I0522 10:10:04.985262   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer conv1, top blob conv1 data: 0.415502
I0522 10:10:04.985370   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer conv1, param blob 0 data: 0.374245
I0522 10:10:04.985461   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer conv1, param blob 1 data: 0.00277251
I0522 10:10:05.029992   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer relu1, top blob conv1 data: 0.167436
I0522 10:10:05.030158   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer relu1, param blob 0 data: 0.230917
I0522 10:10:05.030987   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer conv2, top blob conv2 data: 0.213457
I0522 10:10:05.031092   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer conv2, param blob 0 data: 0.065087
I0522 10:10:05.031244   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer conv2, param blob 1 data: 0.00234184
I0522 10:10:05.031761   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer relu2, top blob conv2 data: 0.0338422
I0522 10:10:05.031859   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer relu2, param blob 0 data: 0.15821
I0522 10:10:05.032014   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer conv2_relu2_0_split, top blob conv2_relu2_0_split_0 data: 0.0338422
I0522 10:10:05.032164   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer conv2_relu2_0_split, top blob conv2_relu2_0_split_1 data: 0.0338422
I0522 10:10:05.032908   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer conv3, top blob conv3 data: 0.013239
I0522 10:10:05.033012   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer conv3, param blob 0 data: 0.0709371
I0522 10:10:05.033102   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer conv3, param blob 1 data: 0.00266559
I0522 10:10:05.033550   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer relu3, top blob conv3 data: 0.00230486
I0522 10:10:05.033643   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer relu3, param blob 0 data: 0.167923
I0522 10:10:05.034057   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer drop, top blob conv3 data: 0.00230195
I0522 10:10:05.034206   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer conv3_drop_0_split, top blob conv3_drop_0_split_0 data: 0.00230195
I0522 10:10:05.034346   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer conv3_drop_0_split, top blob conv3_drop_0_split_1 data: 0.00230195
I0522 10:10:05.034997   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer conv4, top blob conv4 data: 0.00917583
I0522 10:10:05.035099   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer conv4, param blob 0 data: 0.0726901
I0522 10:10:05.035188   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer conv4, param blob 1 data: 0.00386205
I0522 10:10:05.035567   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer relu4, top blob conv4 data: 0.00157258
I0522 10:10:05.035658   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer relu4, param blob 0 data: 0.169566
I0522 10:10:05.035984   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer drop, top blob conv4 data: 0.00157394
I0522 10:10:05.036109   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer conv4_drop_0_split, top blob conv4_drop_0_split_0 data: 0.00157394
I0522 10:10:05.036231   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer conv4_drop_0_split, top blob conv4_drop_0_split_1 data: 0.00157394
I0522 10:10:05.036847   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer conv5, top blob conv5 data: 0.00580002
I0522 10:10:05.036949   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer conv5, param blob 0 data: 0.0789717
I0522 10:10:05.037036   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer conv5, param blob 1 data: 0.00541544
I0522 10:10:05.037344   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer relu5, top blob conv5 data: 0.0010077
I0522 10:10:05.037436   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer relu5, param blob 0 data: 0.171593
I0522 10:10:05.037714   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer drop, top blob conv5 data: 0.00100811
I0522 10:10:05.037840   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer conv5_drop_0_split, top blob conv5_drop_0_split_0 data: 0.00100811
I0522 10:10:05.037955   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer conv5_drop_0_split, top blob conv5_drop_0_split_1 data: 0.00100811
I0522 10:10:05.038496   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer conv6, top blob conv6 data: 0.00340542
I0522 10:10:05.038599   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer conv6, param blob 0 data: 0.0900255
I0522 10:10:05.038691   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer conv6, param blob 1 data: 0.00595053
I0522 10:10:05.038954   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer relu6, top blob conv6 data: 0.000693495
I0522 10:10:05.039048   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer relu6, param blob 0 data: 0.196659
I0522 10:10:05.039283   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer drop, top blob conv6 data: 0.000695216
I0522 10:10:05.039396   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer conv6_drop_0_split, top blob conv6_drop_0_split_0 data: 0.000695216
I0522 10:10:05.039502   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer conv6_drop_0_split, top blob conv6_drop_0_split_1 data: 0.000695216
I0522 10:10:05.040009   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer conv7, top blob conv7 data: 0.00464197
I0522 10:10:05.040110   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer conv7, param blob 0 data: 0.100864
I0522 10:10:05.040400   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer conv7, param blob 1 data: 0.00521081
I0522 10:10:05.040623   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer relu7, top blob conv7 data: 0.000884805
I0522 10:10:05.040717   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer relu7, param blob 0 data: 0.190243
I0522 10:10:05.040915   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer drop, top blob conv7 data: 0.000885196
I0522 10:10:05.041829   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer concatenate1, top blob concatenate1 data: 0.00997691
I0522 10:10:05.042186   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer concatenate1_concatenate1_0_split, top blob concatenate1_concatenate1_0_split_0 data: 0.00997691
I0522 10:10:05.042533   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer concatenate1_concatenate1_0_split, top blob concatenate1_concatenate1_0_split_1 data: 0.00997691
I0522 10:10:05.043359   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer A1, top blob A1 data: 0.00780515
I0522 10:10:05.043488   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer A1, param blob 0 data: 0.096412
I0522 10:10:05.043576   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer A1, param blob 1 data: 0.00323188
I0522 10:10:05.044054   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer reluA1, top blob A1 data: 0.000746234
I0522 10:10:05.044150   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer reluA1, param blob 0 data: 0.0983066
I0522 10:10:05.044556   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer drop, top blob A1 data: 0.00074668
I0522 10:10:05.045150   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer B1, top blob B1 data: 0.00828996
I0522 10:10:05.045250   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer B1, param blob 0 data: 0.0985074
I0522 10:10:05.045353   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer B1, param blob 1 data: 0.00344047
I0522 10:10:05.045567   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer reluB1, top blob B1 data: 0.00125219
I0522 10:10:05.045658   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer reluB1, param blob 0 data: 0.147279
I0522 10:10:05.045874   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer drop, top blob B1 data: 0.00125118
I0522 10:10:05.046331   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer B2, top blob B2 data: 0.00503351
I0522 10:10:05.046430   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer B2, param blob 0 data: 0.106241
I0522 10:10:05.046519   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer B2, param blob 1 data: 0.00502009
I0522 10:10:05.046782   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer reluB2, top blob B2 data: 0.000425956
I0522 10:10:05.046880   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer reluB2, param blob 0 data: 0.0860905
I0522 10:10:05.047076   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer drop, top blob B2 data: 0.000426802
I0522 10:10:05.047433   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer concatenate2, top blob concatenate2 data: 0.000666711
I0522 10:10:05.047777   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer conv8, top blob conv8 data: 0.000599165
I0522 10:10:05.047876   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer conv8, param blob 0 data: 0.132703
I0522 10:10:05.047969   950 net.cpp:603]     [Forward] Layer conv8, param blob 1 data: 0.000346347
I0522 10:10:05.049504   950 net.cpp:591]     [Forward] Layer loss, top blob loss data: nan
I0522 10:10:05.050093   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer loss, bottom blob conv8 diff: 0.000404195
I0522 10:10:05.051265   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer conv8, bottom blob concatenate2 diff: 0.000129882
I0522 10:10:05.051373   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer conv8, param blob 0 diff: 0.000461379
I0522 10:10:05.051470   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer conv8, param blob 1 diff: 0.572021
I0522 10:10:05.051812   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer concatenate2, bottom blob A1 diff: 0.00012783
I0522 10:10:05.051916   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer concatenate2, bottom blob B2 diff: 0.000136037
I0522 10:10:05.052081   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer drop, bottom blob B2 diff: 0.000135995
I0522 10:10:05.052304   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer reluB2, bottom blob B2 diff: 1.31521e-05
I0522 10:10:05.052402   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer reluB2, param blob 0 diff: 0.00102617
I0522 10:10:05.053320   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer B2, bottom blob B1 diff: 2.517e-05
I0522 10:10:05.053484   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer B2, param blob 0 diff: 2.97466e-05
I0522 10:10:05.053581   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer B2, param blob 1 diff: 0.0198924
I0522 10:10:05.053745   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer drop, bottom blob B1 diff: 2.53463e-05
I0522 10:10:05.053974   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer reluB1, bottom blob B1 diff: 4.42646e-06
I0522 10:10:05.054075   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer reluB1, param blob 0 diff: 0.000282126
I0522 10:10:05.055465   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer B1, bottom blob concatenate1_concatenate1_0_split_1 diff: 2.11766e-06
I0522 10:10:05.055578   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer B1, param blob 0 diff: 5.33014e-05
I0522 10:10:05.055784   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer B1, param blob 1 diff: 0.0042211
I0522 10:10:05.056212   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer drop, bottom blob A1 diff: 0.000128165
I0522 10:10:05.056720   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer reluA1, bottom blob A1 diff: 1.4212e-05
I0522 10:10:05.056843   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer reluA1, param blob 0 diff: 0.00145511
I0522 10:10:05.058341   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer A1, bottom blob concatenate1_concatenate1_0_split_0 diff: 1.19995e-05
I0522 10:10:05.058472   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer A1, param blob 0 diff: 0.000175081
I0522 10:10:05.058590   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer A1, param blob 1 diff: 0.0165867
I0522 10:10:05.059746   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer concatenate1_concatenate1_0_split, bottom blob concatenate1 diff: 1.24789e-05
I0522 10:10:05.060521   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer concatenate1, bottom blob conv2_relu2_0_split_1 diff: 1.26877e-05
I0522 10:10:05.060714   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer concatenate1, bottom blob conv3_drop_0_split_1 diff: 1.22685e-05
I0522 10:10:05.060895   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer concatenate1, bottom blob conv4_drop_0_split_1 diff: 1.26432e-05
I0522 10:10:05.061036   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer concatenate1, bottom blob conv5_drop_0_split_1 diff: 1.21001e-05
I0522 10:10:05.061169   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer concatenate1, bottom blob conv6_drop_0_split_1 diff: 1.27764e-05
I0522 10:10:05.061295   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer concatenate1, bottom blob conv7 diff: 1.22628e-05
I0522 10:10:05.061476   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer drop, bottom blob conv7 diff: 1.23225e-05
I0522 10:10:05.061727   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer relu7, bottom blob conv7 diff: 2.36587e-06
I0522 10:10:05.061851   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer relu7, param blob 0 diff: 6.1144e-05
I0522 10:10:05.062788   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer conv7, bottom blob conv6_drop_0_split_0 diff: 4.13267e-06
I0522 10:10:05.062914   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer conv7, param blob 0 diff: 2.07931e-06
I0522 10:10:05.063030   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer conv7, param blob 1 diff: 0.0026707
I0522 10:10:05.063244   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer conv6_drop_0_split, bottom blob conv6 diff: 1.36793e-05
I0522 10:10:05.063462   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer drop, bottom blob conv6 diff: 1.38275e-05
I0522 10:10:05.063757   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer relu6, bottom blob conv6 diff: 3.1853e-06
I0522 10:10:05.063877   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer relu6, param blob 0 diff: 4.92523e-05
I0522 10:10:05.064877   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer conv6, bottom blob conv5_drop_0_split_0 diff: 7.0532e-06
I0522 10:10:05.065002   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer conv6, param blob 0 diff: 4.40123e-06
I0522 10:10:05.065122   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer conv6, param blob 1 diff: 0.00308829
I0522 10:10:05.065369   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer conv5_drop_0_split, bottom blob conv5 diff: 1.46071e-05
I0522 10:10:05.065619   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer drop, bottom blob conv5 diff: 1.48998e-05
I0522 10:10:05.065992   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer relu5, bottom blob conv5 diff: 2.80906e-06
I0522 10:10:05.066118   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer relu5, param blob 0 diff: 8.71506e-05
I0522 10:10:05.067418   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer conv5, bottom blob conv4_drop_0_split_0 diff: 5.48825e-06
I0522 10:10:05.067548   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer conv5, param blob 0 diff: 7.13034e-06
I0522 10:10:05.067664   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer conv5, param blob 1 diff: 0.00280526
I0522 10:10:05.067955   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer conv4_drop_0_split, bottom blob conv4 diff: 1.41262e-05
I0522 10:10:05.068244   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer drop, bottom blob conv4 diff: 1.41677e-05
I0522 10:10:05.068647   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer relu4, bottom blob conv4 diff: 2.68117e-06
I0522 10:10:05.068766   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer relu4, param blob 0 diff: 0.000180559
I0522 10:10:05.070330   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer conv4, bottom blob conv3_drop_0_split_0 diff: 5.59543e-06
I0522 10:10:05.070489   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer conv4, param blob 0 diff: 1.33325e-05
I0522 10:10:05.070636   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer conv4, param blob 1 diff: 0.00274354
I0522 10:10:05.070966   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer conv3_drop_0_split, bottom blob conv3 diff: 1.38212e-05
I0522 10:10:05.071302   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer drop, bottom blob conv3 diff: 1.3831e-05
I0522 10:10:05.071768   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer relu3, bottom blob conv3 diff: 2.75353e-06
I0522 10:10:05.071887   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer relu3, param blob 0 diff: 0.000372754
I0522 10:10:05.073459   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer conv3, bottom blob conv2_relu2_0_split_0 diff: 6.72983e-06
I0522 10:10:05.073590   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer conv3, param blob 0 diff: 0.000126346
I0522 10:10:05.073721   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer conv3, param blob 1 diff: 0.00375996
I0522 10:10:05.074102   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer conv2_relu2_0_split, bottom blob conv2 diff: 1.49227e-05
I0522 10:10:05.074637   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer relu2, bottom blob conv2 diff: 2.39557e-06
I0522 10:10:05.074760   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer relu2, param blob 0 diff: 0.00293634
I0522 10:10:05.076663   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer conv2, bottom blob conv1 diff: 3.39956e-06
I0522 10:10:05.076791   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer conv2, param blob 0 diff: 0.000364487
I0522 10:10:05.076907   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer conv2, param blob 1 diff: 0.00226531
I0522 10:10:05.077531   950 net.cpp:619]     [Backward] Layer relu1, bottom blob conv1 diff: 1.472e-06
I0522 10:10:05.077652   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer relu1, param blob 0 diff: 0.000822316
I0522 10:10:05.078137   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer conv1, param blob 0 diff: 0.000404451
I0522 10:10:05.078263   950 net.cpp:630]     [Backward] Layer conv1, param blob 1 diff: 0.00096731
E0522 10:10:05.084373   950 net.cpp:719]     [Backward] All net params (data, diff): L1 norm = (2017.62, 7.4594); L2 norm = (17.3085, 1.26868)
I0522 10:10:05.084547   950 solver.cpp:239] Iteration 202 (9.42539 iter/s, 0.106096s/1 iters), loss = nan
I0522 10:10:05.084625   950 solver.cpp:258]     Train net output #0: loss = nan (* 1 = nan loss)
I0522 10:10:05.084668   950 sgd_solver.cpp:112] Iteration 202, lr = 0.002
```

I am very confused now, any advice is appreciated, thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide a plot of the loss/train curves?

Comment: sorry,  this log is much long.  the loss is about 80 and reduce to 0.4, then appear nan at iteration 202 depicted in the log above.

Comment: architecture?  what type of loss?

Comment: architecture depicted in the net file and loss is defined by Euclidean loss.